# How to pass asterisk as argument to another script in bash

Tags: bash, special-characters, argument-passing

At first I want to assure that I was looking for the answer for a few hours by now and I've read a lot similar questions but none of them solved my problem.

Straight to the point now:

I have two scripts in bash: one is "tool" that do some stuff for me and the second one is main "for user" script.
I want to pass to the tool script various patterns (like "[A-Za-z0-9]*" or "&")

And here is some code:

```
#!/bin/bash

SET() {

  wz1=`./PREP2.sh $1 $2 '[0-9A-Za-z]\*'`
  wz2=`./PREP2.sh $1 $2 '&'`

  echo $wz1
  echo $wz2


}
SET $1 $2
```

Tool script is actually working if I declare patterns inside like this:

```
line='[0-9A-Za-z]*'
```

But when I pass the same pattern with

```
'\*'
```

I can't get rid of "\" without interpreting "*" as "show all files in catalog".

I've been trying to use eval inside the tool like this:

```
eval echo '$3'
```

But it didn't work.

Full code follow.

User script:

```
#!/bin/bash

SET() {
    #echo '[0-9A-Za-z]*'

    wzor1=$(./PREP2.sh "$1" "$2" '[0-9A-Za-z]*')
    wzor2=`./PREP2.sh $1 $2 '&'`

    echo $wzor1 
    echo $wzor2
}

SET $1 $2 $4
```

Tool code

```
#!/bin/bash


PREP2() {
    #echo "$3"
    wzor="`./PREP.sh $1 $2 | tee linie.txt`"
    #tmp="`echo $wzor | sed 's/,/,%/'`"
    #echo $tmp; 

    ./ZAMIEN_WSZYSTKIE_WYSTAPIENIA.sh linie.txt , @%


    #tmp="`echo $wzor | tr '@' '\n x' | tee linie.txt`"
    tmp="`tr '@' '\n x' < linie.txt | tee linie.txt`"
    llini=`echo "$tmp" | wc -l`

    #echo liczba lini $llini

    i=1
    wzor=""
    while [ $i -le $llini ];
    do

        linia="`eval sed -n -e $i\p linie.txt | cut -d '%' -f2`"
        if [ -z "$linia" ];then
        #linia='[0-9A-Za-z]*'

        linia=`eval '$3'`
        #echo $linia
        fi

        if [ $i -ne 1 ];then
            #echo "kolejna wartosc"
            wzor=$wzor\,$linia
        else
            #echo "pierwsza wartosc"
            wzor=$linia 
        fi

        i=`expr $i + 1`
    done
    echo $wzor
    #wynik="`grep -v "$wzor" $1`"
    #echo "$wynik" > $1
    #echo $nowy_wpis >> $1

}

eval echo "$3"
#PREP2 $1 $2 $3
```

And just to clear things up I don't actually go into procedure because I know it is working weird because of the arguments I put into it.

Comment: Generally, it is better to use the `$(…)` notation instead of the back-ticks.  However, that is tangential to the issue in your question.

Comment: Why do you want the backslash in `'\*'`?  Why not use `'*'`?

Comment: I see your update, I don't see all the `"` I said you should put. You must put them nearly everywhere, especially in the call to the function and all the echos. And in all the calls to prep2.

Comment: Oh, and the code snippet thing here is for web stuff (html/css/Javascript). Please don't use it for shell scripts.

Comment: Sorry for that, may I ask which option allows me to maintain this kind of view of my code but won't display this "run snippet" things?

Comment: Just paste your code, select it and use the code sample formatting button (`{}`)  (Ctrl+K).

Answer (score 2):

Quotes, quotes, quotes and more quotes. And prefer `$()` to backticks, that saves some quoting problems.

```
#!/bin/bash

SET() {

  wz1=$(./PREP2.sh "$1" "$2" '[0-9A-Za-z]*')
  wz2=$(./PREP2.sh "$1" "$2" '&')

  echo "$wz1"
  echo "$wz2"
}
SET "$1" "$2"
```

(BTW: it's unusual to have function names all uppercase. That's usually for environment variables.)

Comment: Sorry, its not working. Still when I use echo $3 in my tool script it shows me all files in my directory.

Comment: Don't `echo $3`, `echo "$3"`.

Comment: Then you're missing quotes somewhere else. Please update your question with a runnable example that reproduces your problem, _including_ how you run it.